# What book is about solo exploration and a return to earth after centuries have passed

Tags: story-identification, novel

Can anyone help?

I am trying to find a book I read twenty plus years ago. The story was about a man who stowed away on an automatic exploration star ship that was crewed by robots. Due to the time dilation effect, the ship returned to a hugely changed earth, many thousands of years after it left. 
It may have had the word "stars" in the title.

Comment: Sounds similar to [A World Out of Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_World_Out_of_Time) but some details do not match.

Comment: This is a common theme, are there other details you can remember? Did the explorer find anything out there? What did he find back on earth? Was the book new when you read it? Do you remember the cover?

Comment: Could nearly be planet of the Apes from that description, but I'm sure you would have mentioned the apes somewhere if it was!!

Comment: Basic idea is similar to [Lem's Return from the Stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_from_the_Stars), but the traval took only about 100 years, and I don't remember if there were any robots on the space ship. Not sure what you understand by "hugely changed" either.

Answer (score 2):

In Rendezvous with Rama (or its sequels) by Arthur Clarke, the astronauts get stranded on the Rama spaceship and return many years later.